# How to prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-x^2+\log(x^2)=-\infty$

Tags: convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

I'm proving the following
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \bigg(-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{7}{2}\log(x^2+2\sqrt{2})\bigg)=-\infty$$
but how to state that $-x^2$ is going faster to $-\infty$ than $\log(x^2)$ is going to $\infty$?

This is a part of a proof for convergence of heavy tailed distributions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Factorize by $x^2$ the whole thing and show $ \ln(x^2)/x^2 \to 0$ at the infinity$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

If we put $t=x^2$, it will be equivalent to prove that

$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\Bigl(-\frac t2+\frac 72\ln(t+2\sqrt{2})\Bigr)=-\infty$$

$$\ln(t+2\sqrt{2})=\ln(t)+\ln(1+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{t})$$

we want
$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\Bigl(t(\frac{-1}{2}+\frac 72\frac{\ln(t)}{t})+\ln(1+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{t})\Bigr)$$
$$=+\infty(\frac{-1}{2}+0) + 0 =-\infty$$

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Factorize first inside the logartihm by $x^2$ then factorize by $x^2$ the whole thing and show $ \ln(x^2)/x^2 \to 0$ at the infinity.

For this, if it isn't a result you're used to use, take substitution :

$$ x=e^t$$

and conclude from the result on $x$.

Knowing that

$$ \dfrac{t}{e^{2t}} \to_{t \to \infty} 0$$

Comment: Thanks, as I've written to the other guys, this helped me get through!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\log(x^2) -x^2$ can be written as

$$\log(x^2) -\log(e^{x^2}) = \log \left(\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}}\right)$$
 and so the limit is
 $$\lim_{x\to\infty}  \log \left(\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}}\right) \\ =  \log \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^{x^2}}\right) \\=\log(\to 0) = -\infty$$

Comment: This is one smooth way. I guess I could've argued that the constants have no impact in the limit and hence the desired follows from this. Thanks!

Comment: @mas2 Of course, you’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \bigg(-x^2+\log(x^2)\bigg)=-\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x^2\bigg(1-\dfrac{\log(x^2)}{x^2} \bigg)=-\infty$$

Expression in brackets tends to $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. This is one of the arguments that I ended up using.